# how to find related code by call stack in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

there,

I'm new to ios, and get a crash log as follows.

my question is, what does the "+ 373" mean in "[ICLRootViewController addHomeScreenViewController] + 373"? how to find related line in ICLRootViewController.m? Line 373 has no relationship with function addHomeScreenViewController() at all.

```
2017-02-09 16:23:28.117 Demo[98834:4764956] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't find view controller.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f77d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110dfb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f7be42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010cda066d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   Demo                               0x0000000109bb63c5 -[ICLRootViewController addHomeScreenViewController] + 373
    5   Demo                               0x0000000109bc252e -[ICLRootViewController onNewsButtonClicked] + 542
    6   Demo                               0x0000000109a2b9ce __51-[ICLHomeScreenToolbarViewController initWebToolbar]_block_invoke_2 + 62
    7   Demo                               0x0000000109dee0f1 -[ICLWebViewToolbar didClickNewsButton:] + 305
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f5b18bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f737c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010f737f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f736e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f61f545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f620c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    14  Demo                               0x0000000109a96a80 -[ICLInteractionDetectionWindow sendEvent:] + 688
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010f5cd9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010fdba72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010fdb3463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f1c761 __CFRUNLOICL_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f0198c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f00e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f00884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011473ba6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010f5afc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  Demo                               0x000000010981da1f main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113ccd68d start + 1
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: reason: 'Can't find view controller.'

Comment: What are you trying to do ??

Comment: @AbhishekGupta um, I means how to retrace the crash log, and find which line of the code make this crash.

Comment: Use debugger where you perform action.

Answer (score 0):

- 373 is an offset from the beginning of the function symbol listed in the backtrace.  The crash reporter didn't have access to debug information so it couldn't do the translation from address to source lines.

If you have the binary that is exhibiting this crash and it's dSYM, however, you can figure this out by hand.  You won't be able to tell anything from the absolute addresses in the crash, since macOS and iOS randomize load locations.  That's why having it in "symbol + offset" form is handy.  So, load your binary & dSYM into the debugger and do:

```
(lldb) disassemble -m -n "-[ICLRootViewController addHomeScreenViewController]"
```

That command will disassemble the code for the function passed to the `-n` argument, showing a mixed source & assembly view of this method.  The assembly output will be listed with the offsets, so just find `<+373>` and the source lines above it will show you where it comes from.  If this is optimized code, the source -> address mapping can sometimes be confusing, but the mixed view might help you sort that out as well.

Answer (score -3):

perhaps you can find the answer in the 4th line displaying,

```html
4   Demo                               0x0000000109bb63c5 -[ICLRootViewController addHomeScreenViewController] + 373
```

where is the last code in your project that run